# Push a record datatype into a stack

Tags: generics, stack, record, ada

I am new to Ada and I can't figure out how to update a field in a record and push the record into a stack instantiated with a generic package.

I have tried using genericS.vehicleName and garageBay.vehicleName to no avail.

```
--Snippet
type vehicle is array(1..15) of character;
type vName is array(1..8) of character;
type garageBay is record
    vehicleType: vehicle;
    vehicleName: vName;
    time2Fix: integer;
    startTime: integer;
    finishTime: integer;
end record;
begin
get(lowerbound);
get(upperbound);
declare
package genericS is new gstack(lowerbound,upperbound, garageBay);
use genericS;
begin
    put("Enter vehicle name: " ); 
    get(garageBay.vehicleName); 
    tpush(garageBay);
end;

--Errors
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-8 -c gusestack.adb
gusestack.adb:24:21: invalid prefix in selected component "garageBay"
gusestack.adb:25:23: invalid use of subtype mark in expression or call
gnatmake: "gusestack.adb" compilation error
```

Comment: Garagebay is a [sub]type. You're attempting to use it as an object (a variable). A type is not an object. You need to declare an object of type Garagebay and operate on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be confused between a type and an instance of a type. You define the type garbageBay but never create an instance of that type. A type declaration defines the structure of a type, including the amount of memory required for an instance of the type. It does not allocate memory for all imaginable instances of a type. You must create an instance of garbageBay in the declarative section of your code such as

```
element : garbageBay;
```

You can then modify your code to say

```
get(element.vehicleName);
tpush(element);
```

Comment: How will i go about popping the record. Do I have to pop each individual element ?

Comment: Each pop operation will pop an entire garbageBay object, including all its fields containing the values the object contained when it was pushed onto the stack.

Comment: I have tried that using tpop(element) and it works, but in my adb file I have put(x) to print the output of the pop operation and it throws errors concerning the IO. So I guess my question is , is there a special IO package to print a record to the screen

Comment: No. You must created your own customized output procedure. For instance, you define the types vehicle and vName to be arrays of character rather than type String. Type vehicle and type vName are not type String. You have defined them as separate types.

Comment: I should do that within my .adb file that contains the push and pop operations ? And to do that wouldn’t I also have to declare garageBay in the .adb  or .ads file so it can recognize the record data type

Comment: I would create a generic package for your stack ADT and another package for the garageBay type. I would put the procedure to print an item of garageBay in the package containing the definition of the garageBay type. Your program should then "with" each package, instantiate the generic for use with the garageBay type, and call all the subprograms from either package as needed.

Comment: thanks , I’ll try and figure it out using your idea. I’m still learning Ada while I work on this , so it’s been going really slow.  I already have a generic package for the stack , I will work on the package for the record